# Counting how many times a condition succeeds in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a table A with real time values in it.

```
   
Amount  Count   Pct1    Pct2

 300    2   0.000   100.000
 1,891  2   0.001   100.000
 500    2   0.000   100.000
 100    2   0.000   100.000
 1,350  2   0.001   100.000
 2,648  2   0.001   100.000
 2,255  2   0.001   100.000
 500    2   0.000   100.000
 200    2   0.000   30.441
 10     2   0.000   100.000
 1,928  2   0.001   100.000
 40     2   0.000   100.000
 200    2   0.000   100.000
 256    2   0.000   100.000
 254    2   0.000   100.000
 100    2   0.001   100.000
 50     1   0.000   33.333
 1,512  2   0.001   100.000
```

I have a table B with a set of conditions. I want to generate the Condition success count in SAS. i.e. If I pass the row 1 in the below table as a condition to the table A it succeeds 2 times. I am using a join to generate a cartesin product and its not efficient. I want an efficient way to solve this problem (similar to what countifs function does in excel). Thanks a lot for your help.

Amount  Count   Pct1    Pct2    Condion Success Count
1,576   2   0   100 4
1,537   2   0   100 4
1,484   2   0   100 5
1,405   2   0   100 5
1,290   2   0   100 6
1,095   2   0   100 6
948 2   0   100 6
932 2   0   100 6
914 2   0   100 6
887 2   0   100 6
850 2   0   100 6
774 2   0   100 6
707 2   0   100 6
704 2   0   100 6
695 2   0   100 6
646 2   0   100 6
50  1   0   5.42    16
50  1   0   5.42    16

Comment: codition example: table a values amount >= 1576 and count>=2 and pct1>=0.00 and pct2>=2. In the above exaple 'table b' has a condition success count of 2 denoting the success of this condition when passed on to table A.

Comment: Should you say `pct2=> 100`? But still I don't get this. Isn't there 4 rows which satisfy that condition in table A:   `1,891  2   0.001   100.000 |
 2,648  2   0.001   100.000 |
 2,255  2   0.001   100.000 |
 1,928  2   0.001   100.000 |`

Comment: Hi Pekka, you are right. Its Pct2>100 and I have corrected the output. Typed erroneously by mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you have tried join to make to make a cartesian product. However, since you didn't post any code I am not sure if you tried to make full product and then calculate the rows. Doing the counting in one SQL statement is much faster since actually full cartesian product is not written anywhere. Like this:

```
proc sql;
    create table tableC as
    select c.*, coalesce(s,0) as SuccessCount from TableB c
    left join (
    select id, count(*) as s from TableA a,TableB b
    where 
    a.amount >= b.amount and
    a.count >= b.count and
    a.pct1 >= b.pct1 and
    a.pct2 >= b.pct2
    group by id
    ) as d 
    on c.id = d.id
    ;
quit;
```

Note that tableB needs to have some unique id column. You should always have some column to use as id but if you don't have it already simple create it like this for example:

```
data tableB;
    set tableB;
    id = _N_;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot pekka. Its a lot better than what I was doing. I was trying to add a key_id = 1 in both the tables and joining it to make a cartesian product and then counting the successes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi. Good that it works. You can accept the answer with the tick box if you feel it solves your problem.